# Tail recursion vs non tail recursion

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

I have been through the tail recursion with below definition

**A recursive function is said to be tail-recursive if the recursive call is the last thing done by the function, there is no need to keep record of the previous state.**

I checked [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/what-is-tail-recursion) answer as well. But I still have a query:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    doit(3);
}

public static void doit(int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        return;
    }
    doit(n-1);
    fact2(n);
    doit(n-1);
}

public static void fact2(int n) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

In the above recursive calls, can we call this above tail-recursive or non-tail-recursive? Or we can split it the code says that the last line after fact2(n) is tail recursion and line before fact2(n) is non-tail recursion?

and if I change the above calls to

```
public static void doit(int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        return;
    }
    doit(n-1);
    fact2(n);
    doit(n-1);
    fact2(n)
}
```

Would this be tail-recursive?

Comment: the recursive call is not the last thing done by this function so it is not tail recursion

Comment: In both versions, there are multiple recursive calls, and neither are the last thing the function does, so no, it isn't. For the function to be tail recursive, there can only be one recursive call total, and it has to be the last thing in the function.

Comment: @DylanMcNamee: more precisely, there can be at most one recursive call per invocation.  The code can have multiple branches with different recursive calls, so long as no more than one is executed when I call the function.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - we are in agreement. My description was about dynamic behavior, yours is about static properties that result in the same dynamic behavior.

Comment: @DylanMcNamee: Absolutely.  I didn't think we disagreed, only that phrased like that might have people asking, "But why do they say function `xyz` is tail-recursive, when it clearly has two recursive calls?"

Comment: So if we have more than one recursive calls in function (and that function is calling itself) it would be non-tail recursive? As there are more than 1 recursive call in function